# query_posts for child pages

Tags: query-posts, pages

I am having problems looking for info on the codex on how to query for child pages. It seems to be missing the reference for the available parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah they've moved the parameters to [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). You're looking for the post_parent parameter.

Answer (score 1):

All the parameters for `query_posts` are listed in [WP_Query page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query).

However, there's a function [get_children()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) for get child pages that you should use instead. Its parameters are **similar** to `query_posts`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$pages = WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_parent' => $parent_id,
        'post_type' => 'page'
    )
);
// code to display
```